# jQuery resize window width noconflict mode

Tags: jquery, css, resize

Trying to change the border width to the width of the window.
Got this code to work:

```
jQuery(window).ready(function($) {  

    var windowWidth = $('#portfolio_title .container').outerWidth();

    $('.topBorder').css({'border-right-width':(windowWidth)+'px'});
    $('.btmBorder').css({'border-left-width':(windowWidth)+'px'});

    $(window).resize( function(){
        var windowWidth = $('#portfolio_title .container').outerWidth();
        $('.topBorder').css({'border-right-width':(windowWidth)+'px'});
        $('.btmBorder').css({'border-left-width':(windowWidth)+'px'});
    });
});
```

But it is not pretty
Trying to optimise it like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(myWidth);

jQuery(window).resize(myWidth);

function myWidth($){
    var windowWidth = $('#portfolio_title .container').outerWidth();

    $('.topBorder').css({'border-right-width':(windowWidth)+'px'});
    $('.btmBorder').css({'border-left-width':(windowWidth)+'px'});
};
```

document ready works but the resize does not.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass `$` to `myWidth` and expect it to be `jQuery`. In `myWidth` `$` would be an event object. This will make `$` jQuery for you without worry on conflict.

```
(function($, window, document){

  jQuery(document).ready(myWidth);

  jQuery(window).resize(myWidth);

  function myWidth(){
      var windowWidth = $('#portfolio_title .container').outerWidth();

      $('.topBorder').css({'border-right-width':(windowWidth)+'px'});
      $('.btmBorder').css({'border-left-width':(windowWidth)+'px'});
  }; 

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 0):

The document ready handler receives the jQuery object as the first argument where as `resize` handler receives the event object as the argument.

So when `myWidth` is called by the resize event the `$` refers to the `resize` event not the jQuery object.

You can fix it by registering the resize handler then then manually triggering the handler on dom ready as given below

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var windowWidth = $('#portfolio_title .container').outerWidth();
        $('.topBorder').css({
            'border-right-width': (windowWidth) + 'px'
        });
        $('.btmBorder').css({
            'border-left-width': (windowWidth) + 'px'
        });
    }).resize();
});
```

Comment: This didn't work. It did the initial resize but didn't work on resizing the window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var windowWidth = $('#portfolio_title .container').outerWidth();
$(function() {  
    $('.topBorder').css({'border-right-width':(windowWidth)+'px'});
    $('.btmBorder').css({'border-left-width':(windowWidth)+'px'});

    $(window).resize( function(){
        $('.topBorder').css({'border-right-width':(windowWidth)+'px'});
        $('.btmBorder').css({'border-left-width':(windowWidth)+'px'});
    });
});
```